# PHPMailer PDF attachment causing email invalid

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send several attachments via email. Everything is working fine, but I'm experiencing an issue with specific PDF file. I have tested this PDF file and it is valid, but when I send it using PHPMailer, the email is blank and has no other attachment.

There is a warning in the email message header when I'm trying to attach this PDF.

```
X-Amavis-Alert: BAD HEADER SECTION, MIME error: error: unexpected end of preamble
Received: from mxload.webglobe.sk ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (inmail-07.webglobe.sk [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP id vfqgUKdsRNId for <xxx@gmail.com>; Fri, 27 Jul 2018 21:47:50 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from xxx.com (Authenticated sender: xxx@gmail.com) by mxload.syphon.sk (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 0D8F5106F91E9 for <xxx@gmail.com>; Fri, 27 Jul 2018 21:47:50 +0200 (CEST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=xxx.com; s=mail; t=1532720870; bh=frcCV1k9oG9oKj3dpUqdJg1PxRT2RSN/XKdLCPjaYaY=; h=Date:To:From:Reply-To:Subject:From; b=ikfBIXZzjiDAm5ejZTW9oheNCEbTR1bRNrfnVarkKj/0o64yZkt//ay/R5X8L3euu
     ciYBDh+sgSbe0gk57k5J5ZdGF6U5IOT0BVyV7bNppD2LKLhyJSLIPzHTUcPtSzlC8s
     5NkHxir6QzE8dKiP+ybmPa6e/yWxN83HQeVGlc/k=
Date: Fri, 27 Jul 2018 21:47:49 +0200
To: xxx@gmail.com
From: XXX <xxx@gmail.com>
Reply-To: XXX <xxx@gmail.com>
Subject: Attachments
Message-ID: <0q7W0WmzhOOO0yRorjRnxQmNbWMoSndlVgjE9xoBzQ@xxx.com>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.5 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="b1_0q7W0WmzhOOO0yRorjRnxQmNbWMoSndlVgjE9xoBzQ"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

--b1_0q7W0WmzhOOO0yRorjRnxQmNbWMoSndlVgjE9xoBzQ


--b1_0q7W0WmzhOOO0yRorjRnxQmNbWMoSndlVgjE9xoBzQ--
```

Comment: PDF is available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebxg863j2ilywfm/test2.pdf?dl=0

Comment: `MIME error: error: unexpected end of preamble`... What does your code actually look like?

Comment: @Samuel which code do you mean? PHP code sending email via PHPMailer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that the file permission was set incorrectly (no read access).